# How to upload the files to one drive using c#

Tags: c#, .net, onedrive

I searched a lot for correct article where i can find some example for doing authentication and upload files to OneDrive using c#. please help me in finding the correct sample of code or examples

Comment: will this work one drive

Comment: No, my bad, I confused it with Google Drive. Microsoft has articles on how to push files to OneDrive, See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/sample-code?view=odsp-graph-online

Answer (score 0):

My solution was just to copy the file into the local OneDrive folder: `$@"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OneDrive")}\Folder`.

The file will be synced up to the cloud soon if you log in to OneDrive.